# Destroy function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my app which is going to create dropdown selectors soon as it find a folder inside a folder. What is going to display in the end is a index.html file. If there is a file called index.html, it will be loaded in a iframe. Now I could stop showing the index file and stop creating a new dropdown selector soon as that file is inside folder. But if there are other folders as js or css or images, it will show them. Can anyone help me to modify the code as soon as it get and index.html file to stop looking for another folder inside and stop creating a new folder.

here is a link where I have the app running http://tdhtestserver.herobo.com/

Here is the code which is looking for folders and html files and is going to create dropdown selectors

```
function processNewDFData( respObj, $currentSelectItem, strCurrentPath ) {
  fsStructure[strCurrentPath] = {'subfolders':[], 'subshtmls':[]};
  var hasFolder = false;
  if ( (respObj.subfolders.length > 0) || (respObj.subshtmls.length > 0) ) {
    for( var i = 0; i < respObj.subfolders.length; i++ ) {
      fsStructure[strCurrentPath].subfolders.push( respObj.subfolders[i] );
      hasFolder = true;
    }

    for( var i = 0; i < respObj.subshtmls.length; i++ ) {
      fsStructure[strCurrentPath].subshtmls.push( respObj.subshtmls[i] );
    }
  }

  rendSelects( $currentSelectItem, strCurrentPath, hasFolder );
}

function rendSelects($currentSelectItem, strPath, hasFolder) {
       var currentSelectLvl = (null === $currentSelectItem ? -1 : parseInt($currentSelectItem.attr('data-selector-level'))),
        nextOneSelectorHtml =
            '<select class="dropdown selectpicker" name="dd" ' 
            + 'data-selector-level="' + (currentSelectLvl + 1) + '" ' 
            + 'data-path="' + strPath + '" '
            + 'onchange="onFsSelectChange(this)"'
            + '><option text selected> -- select an option -- </option>';

 $('div.selectors-container select.dropdown').each(function (i, el) {
  if(parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-selector-level'))>currentSelectLvl) {
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
            $(el).selectpicker('destroy');
  }
 });
   if ( fsStructure[strPath].subfolders.length > 0 ) {
    for(var i=0; i < fsStructure[strPath].subfolders.length; i++) {
        if(fsStructure[strPath].subfolders[i] != 'highlighted'){
        nextOneSelectorHtml += 
          '<option ' + 
            'class="subfolder-option" ' + 
            'data-subfolder="' + fsStructure[strPath].subfolders[i] + '">' + 
              fsStructure[strPath].subfolders[i] + 
          '</option>';
        }
    }
  }

  if ( fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls.length > 0 ) {
    for(var i=0; i < fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls.length; i++) {
         if (fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] != 'highlighted.html' && fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] != 'index.html'){
        nextOneSelectorHtml += 
          '<option ' + 
            'class="html-page-option" ' + 
            'data-html-page-name="' + fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] + '">' + 
              fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] + 
          '</option>';
        }else{high( strPath+'/highlighted.html');} 
    }
  }

  if ( fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls.length > 0 ) {
    for(var i=0; i < fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls.length; i++) {
        if (fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] != 'index.html'){
        nextOneSelectorHtml += 
          '<option ' + 
            'style="display: none;" ' +
            'class="html-page-option" ' + 
            'data-html-page-name="' + fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] + '">' + 
              fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] + 
          '</option>';
        }else{playSwf( strPath+'/index.html');}
    }
  }

  if(hasFolder) {
    nextOneSelectorHtml += '</select>';
    $('div.selectors-container').append( nextOneSelectorHtml );
    $('div.selectors-container').trigger('dropdownadded.mh');
  }
}
```

**SOLVED**

Comment: You should add your solution as a seperate answer instead of extending your question.

Comment: Please follow @wooer 's suggestion and don't add your answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was to add `hasFolder = false;` on this row `else{playSwf( strPath+'/index.html');hasFolder = false;}`